# table row data displaying twice on web

Tags: php, mysql, web-applications, xampp

I am creating an online baseball management game, i have xxampp installed on my local pc, and the code i have written so far displays as i like it on the localhost,
however when i transfer these files to the webserver, it displays each row twice
anyone have any idea why that would be?

```
<?php
include("./Lib/Database.php");
$db = new Database(false);
$query_string = "SELECT * FROM player, team WHERE TeamID AND PlayerTeamID ='".$_SESSION['TEAMID']."'";

$db->Query($query_string);
$db->SelectNextResult();
while ($row = $db->SelectNextResult()) {
echo("<DIV class='ComponentMain' align='center'>");
echo("<DIV class='ComponentTitle'>Team Name</DIV>");
echo("<BR><TABLE align='center'>");
{
  echo("<TR bgcolor='#DDDDDD'><TD colspan='6'><A HREF='./Player.php?ID=".$db-   >GetResult("PlayerID")."'><DIV class='PlayerName'>".$db->GetResult("PlayerPrenameValue")." ".$db->GetResult("PlayerNameValue")."</DIV></A></TD><TD align='right'><IMG src='./Gfx/Flags/". $db->GetResult("PlayerNationID").".png'/></TD></TR>");
echo("<TR><TD>    Age:</TD><TD>".$db->GetResult("PlayerAge")."</TD><TD>Potential:</TD><TD>".$db->GetResult("Potential")."</TD><TD>Health:</TD><TD>".$db->GetResult("Health")."</TD></TR>");
echo("<TR><TD colspan='5' align='center'><IMG src='./Gfx/Faces/Face.png'/></TD>");
{
    echo("<TR><TD>Contact:</TD><TD>".$db->GetResult("Contact")."</TD><TD>Power:</TD><TD>".$db->GetResult("Power")."</TD><TD>Vision:</TD><TD>".$db->GetResult("Vision")."</TD></TR>");
    echo("<TR><TD>Fielding:</TD><TD>".$db->GetResult("Fielding")."</TD><TD>Intelligence:</TD><TD>".$db->GetResult("Intelligence")."</TD><TD>Speed:</TD><TD>".$db->GetResult("Speed")."</TD></TR>");
    echo("<TR><TD>Morale:</TD><TD>".$db->GetResult("Morale")."</TD><TD>Pitching Skill:</TD><TD>".$db->GetResult("Skills")."</TD><TD>Velocity:</TD><TD>".$db->GetResult("Velocity")."</TD></TR>");
}
echo("<TR><TD colspan='5' align='center'>------------------------------------</TD></TR>");

}
echo("</TABLE>");
echo("<BR></DIV>");
}
$db->Close();
?>
```

as far as the $db commands those are not the issue,
i think it could be the while im really not sure as usually when i do this on other projects i have no issues,
this is a larger project though and the first of its type i have attempted
its just rather wierd, any advice would be appreciated, anothe wierd thing i noticed
was that in amongst my files for this site i have a file that defines some elements for the webapp, and on xampp no issues, on webserver it requires me to close the opening php tag in the file to accept the class Site lol so i dunno maybe its the webserver ?

Comment: had you checked your database and insert function that this only one row per entry in your database

Comment: too many { , and why 2X SelectNextResult();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are problems in your query (I've split it into multiple lines so it won't scroll off the page):

```
$query_string = "SELECT * FROM player, team " .
  "WHERE TeamID AND PlayerTeamID = '" . $_SESSION['TEAMID'] . "'";
```

Here's what I see:

- The `WHERE TeamID` will include any `TeamID` that isn't zero.
- You're joining tables `player` and `team` but you don't have a join condition. That means that if your database has two teams, each player will be doubled. If your database has three teams, each player will be tripled. And so on.

I'd be willing to bet that your local database has one team and the database you access from your web server has two teams. Your query should be something like this:

```
$query_string = "SELECT * FROM player, team " .
  "WHERE team.TeamID = player.PlayerTeamID " .
  "  AND player.PlayerTeamID = '" . $_SESSION['TEAMID'] . "'";
```

I've guessed at the second line above. Substitute the columns that are used to tie the tables together and you'll be fine.

Or better yet, use ANSI joins because (a) they're the standard and (b) they make it plain what your join logic is. This query does exactly the same as the one above:

```
$query_string = "SELECT * FROM player " .
  "INNER JOIN team ON team.TeamID = player.PlayerTeamID " .
  "WHERE player.PlayerTeamID = '" . $_SESSION['TEAMID'] . "'";
```

You may also have issues with your PHP code, but if you fix the query first you'll find them soon enough.

Finally, a suggestion: use MySQL Workbench or the MySQL Command Line to test your queries before putting them into the PHP code. You'll save a lot of time.

Comment: good call on the joins, fixed everything as needed, as far as the excessive brackets they are just left over from various testing i have been doing today, i do need to clean it up, very much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have too many brackets.

Place:

> ```
> echo("<DIV class='ComponentMain' align='center'>");
> echo("<DIV class='ComponentTitle'>Team Name</DIV>");
> echo("<BR><TABLE align='center'>");
> ```

Before while() statement. The logic something like this:

> ```
> <table>
> <tr>
> <?php while( $sql = $row ) { ?>
> <tr>
>    <td><?php echo $row->stuff; ?></td>
>    <td><?php echo $row->stuff1; ?></td>>
> </tr>
> <?php } ?>
> </tr>
> </table>
> ```

Hope it work !

Answer (score 0):

try this code ,and what u see

```
include("./Lib/Database.php");
$db = new Database(false);
$query_string = "SELECT * FROM player, team WHERE TeamID AND PlayerTeamID ='".$_SESSION['TEAMID']."'";
$db->Query($query_string);
while ($row = $db->SelectNextResult()) {
$row->PlayerID; // or $row['PlayerID'];  // or $db->GetResult("Contact")
}
$db->Close();
```